# JMeter creates two user sessions for 200 threads

Tags: session, cookies, jmeter, performance-testing, moodle

I am trying to run a performance test on a Moodle application using JMeter. the test plan contains two  Stepping Thread Groups which will start 400 threads in total.

Each thread will fetch unique user id from a csv. I have added HTTP Cookie Manager to each group and set to clear cookies each iteration.

I expect JMeter to get a new user session for each iteration with unique user id.
But, while running the test I observed in New Relic that there are only two user sessions are established.

Am I missing something?

Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put Debug Sampler and check what is read from your CSV file. Make sure each thread reads a unique user. Clarify your question to say if it does or doesn't. If it does, then please provide workflow of your script. If it doesn't you will need to fix CSV.

Comment: @Kiril S. thanks. I have added the debug sampler and I could see for each iteration new user id is picked up from the csv. but, still I am seeing only one or two user sessions.  Workflow of my script is just Login, navigate to another page and logout.

Comment: In that case you need to know what application is doing to identify unique user session, i.e.: set cookies? set a unique session id? pass session/cookie in the header/body of each request? I would just compare debug view in browser of the request after login to your request in jmeter